# Unable to view System Requirements for ClearCase 8.0.x

Tags: clearcase

I am trying to view the IBM Rational Clearcase 8.0.x System Requirements on google. But i could found the below links but none of them are having the details for version -8.0.x.

```
[1] https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/node/589803
[2] https://www.ibm.com/software/reports/compatibility/clarity/index.html
```

From the [2] link i have searched in the all the categories however in all the details available only for 9.0 version. So please guide me to view for 8.0.x version.

Answer (score 0):

For older products like ClearCase 8, it is better to refer to the [release notes page](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/rational-clearcase-version-800x-release-notes).

The [ClearCase 8 manual](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_8.0.0/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.help.ic.doc/helpindex_clearcase.html) also has a "[Hardware and software requirements](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_8.0.0/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ms_install.doc/topics/c_hw_sw_reqts.htm)" page fairly complete.

But the new "[Software Product Compatibility Reports](http://www.ibm.com/software/reports/compatibility/clarity/index.html)" only references ClearCase 9.x indeed.